# Passing local variable to another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I am pulling in data from an API that has several options for an image and I have a function that I want to call in from several other functions called `validateBoxArt` which picks the URL of the largest image available.

I'm calling it in another function like so:

```
$.each(data.results, function(index, game) {
    validateBoxArt(game);
    $('#dynamic-content').append('<a href="title.html?id=' + game.id + '">' +
        '<div class="row game-preview">' +
        '<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">' +
        '<img src="' + boxArt + '" class="game-preview-image">' +
        '<h2 style="display:inline-block; padding-left:5px;" class="post-title">' + game.name + ' <span class="small">' + year + '</span></h2>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</a>' +
        '<hr>');
    });
}
```

The function itsself:

```
function validateBoxArt(game) {
    if (game.image.super_url != undefined) {
        var boxArt = staticUrl+game.image.super_url;
    }
    else if (game.image.large_url != undefined) {
        var boxArt = staticUrl+game.image.large_url;
    }
    else if (game.image.medium_url != undefined) {
        var boxArt = staticUrl+game.image.medium_url;
    }
    else if (game.image.small_url != undefined) {
        var boxArt = staticUrl+game.image.small_url;
    }
    else{
        var boxArt = 'http://placehold.it/500x350';
    }
    console.log(boxArt);
    return boxArt;
}
```

Box art in the first function is returning an error saying undefined, but the variable appears in the console log, how do I retrieve the variable in the initial function so it is defined?

Comment: you are not using the value returned from `validateBoxArt` method

Comment: yes you are not returing the value  instead of `validateBoxArt(game);
` try `var boxArt  = validateBoxArt(game);`

Comment: Is `http://placehold.it/` your static url ? I don't think you need so many `var` declarations..

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the string retuned from `validateBoxArt()` to a variable:

```
var boxArt = validateBoxArt(game);
```